# Google Tag Manager Event Fired but not tracked in FF, but in Chrome

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a trigger in GTM to track all clicks on a specific css selector (`#navi_overlay a`):

[image]

Then I have created an tag to track this click as an Google Analytics event:

[image]

I have tested it in Chrome (and Edge) and everything works fine. The event is triggered and I can see the click in realtime google analytics. But in Firefox
the event is triggered (as i can see it in GTM preview mode), but click is not shown up in Google Analytics Realtime preview.

Has anyone an idea, why its not working in FF?

Comment: Can you verify that the event isn't tracking with Firefox (or other dev tools for FF)? If things are working, then you should see the GA hit in the Network analysis panel.

Comment: I have now tried out the same page on my notebook with firefox29 on it and it worked. So it has maybe somthing to do with the latest version of firefox. And no, in network tab, nothing is shown - no request to ga is done.

Comment: OK, so things are working in one version of FF but not the other? Can you share the site and the event you are tracking?

Comment: Yes. The site is http://www.gutekueche.at/ . There you need to hover over one of the top-navigation points (for example REZEPTE or COCKTAILS) and in the flyoutmenu, you have to click on one of the images.

Comment: But as far as I can see, it doesn't work for all links. Some are not tracking in FF (earlier version as well). There is no logic behind this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked in CR v49 and FF v43.0.1, and I can see the events being sent in the Network panels. Looks good as far as I can tell, and I think you're firing these through GTM, so I can't really check any further. Are the links that are not firing always consistent?

Comment: Have you considered that it might be the blocking of third party cookies in FF? And my other suggestion would be to try with Configure Trigger option Check Validation set to OFF. Just saying, you might already have considered both.

Comment: I have a similar error since FF 57.0 - The conversion rate is 100 times lower than other versions of this FF but not null.
- The other events are working properly.